# Program runs in python but in EC2-Cronjob/AWS Lambda skips appending list

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cron, cron-task

```
def power(self):
        #json= jsonObj.json()
        buildingName='someName'
        now= datetime.datetime.now()
        end= now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        start=  (now - datetime.timedelta(minutes=30)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        jsonObj= self.solarEdgeClient("power", startTime= start, endTime= end)
        values = jsonObj['power']['values']
        tsData= []
        for value in values:
            ts= str(SolarEdge.timetoUTC(value['date']))
            unit = str(jsonObj['power']['unit'])
            point_id='{}.SolarEdge.Power'.format(buildingName)
            if value['value'] == None:
                pass
            else:
                quantity = float(value['value'])
                tsData.append({'point_id':point_id,'ts':ts, 'quantity': quantity, 'unit': unit})
        return tsData
```

That is the function I am calling to get data, the issue the list append here. It works when I run the code in sublime. However, when I use cron I get empty list. This is how I am calling the function:

```
def create_history(self, history):
    #print(history)
    client = Client(url=STAGNIG_URL)
    return client.api_request('POST', DEVICE_HOSTORY_ENDPOINT, payload= history)

def  semi_hourly(event= None, context= None):
     history = SolarEdge.power() 
     time.sleep(15)
     SolarEdge.create_history(history)
     return print(history)
```

This is just a snippet. I know the code works, but when running in Cron, the power() function is skipping. It does the same for AWS lamda function.

```
semi_hourly()
```

Comment: Additional information will be helpful. Use some `print()` statement inside AWS Lambda to debug your source code. Find exactly where your script skipping the code.

Comment: I have placed print() on all the  functions I am using. It seems, the code is completely skipping, for loop in the power() function. It's only taking the tsData as [], and it's not appending the code. It's completely skipping the for loop. I placed a print element in it, and it's not writing.